# Is there a way to get functionality in Dart similar to Swift's List.enumerated() method?

Tags: dart

In Swift, if there's a list, you can iterate over it somewhat like so

```
for (index, val) in itemList {
    //do stuff
}
```

I'm trying to recreate that same functionality in Dart, but this is the best that I've come up with -

```
extension ListExtensions<T> on List<T> {
  List<List<dynamic>> enumerated (){
    List<List<dynamic>> result = List(this.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
      result[i] = [i, this[i]];
    return result;
  }
}
```

1. Is there anything wrong with the way I've done this, or any shortcomings you see
2. Is there a way to make it better?

Here's an example usage of the way it currently is

```
var list = ["hello", "world", "this", "is", "an", "example"];
for( var pair in list.enumerated()){
    print('${pair[0]}: ${pair[1]}');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```dart
for (var entry in list.asMap().entries) {
  print("index: ${entry.key}, value: ${entry.value}");
}
```

If you want to write something more direct, your approach is fine. I'd use a class for the index-and-value value, so that it can be typed correctly. Maybe:

```dart
class IndexedValue<T> {
  final int index;
  final T value;
  Pair(this.index, this.value);
}
extension EnumerateExt<T> on List<T> {
  Iterable<IndexedValue<T>> get enumerated sync {
    var i = 0;
    for (var value in this) yield IndexedValue(i++, value);
  }
}
```

Then you can iterate over the indices as:

```dart
  for (var iv in list.enumerated) {
    print("index: ${iv.index}, value: ${iv.value}");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can directly iterate over the `List` using `for-in` `loop`:

```
void main() {
  List<String> testCases =  ['Hello','World','this','is','an','examples'];
  for(var testCase in testCases){
    print('$testCase, ${testCases.indexOf(testCase)}');
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, 0
World, 1
this, 2
is, 3
an, 4
example, 5
```

**Note:** `indexOf` Returns the first index of [element] in this list. So repeated element wont show the correct index.

For that the index based `for` `loop` will work:

```
for(int index=0; index<testCases.length; index++){
    print('${testCases[index]}, $index');
  }
```

Also there is `asMap()` which returns a `Map` form of the `List`. [asMap() Doc](https://api.dart.dev/be/159029/dart-core/List/asMap.html)